# Enclose a list of tags (taghelper) by a parent tag

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I need to achieve like below

```
<MyTagList>
    <MyTag></MyTag>
    <MyTag></MyTag>
</MyTagList>
```

When ever I use `MyTag` in design time, it need to be enclosed automaticaly by `MyTagList` or `MyTag` should error that it must be enclosed by `MyTagList`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this today at design time. You can however do it partially at runtime by utilizing `TagHelperContext.Items`. By using the `Items` property you can ensure that each tag is enclosed by a parent tag and throw if it's not. Insert an indicator into the `Items` bag in your parent element and verify that it exists in child elements.

As for supporting this in the future there are two issues open to add design time support:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/255
- https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/474

Hope this helps!