# ASP.NET 5 Complex TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Is it possible to build complex taghelper in ASP.NET 5 where the custom tag have child elements/tags of a certain type?

```
<blockSection columns="2" labelPosition="left">
   <inputField for="name" />
   <inputField for="email" required="true"/>
</blockSection>
```

The in the above example, the blockSection will be a TagHelper that only accepts inputField tags.

Comment: Certainly, check for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/31553298/1836935

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I think he's referring to enforcing what elements can exist under the tag `<blockSection>`.

Comment: You are right, looks like I didn't properly understand the question :) Nice problem though.

Comment: Maybe this blog post about complex custom taghelpers can give you some clues http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/12/28/complex-custom-tag-helpers-in-mvc-6.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a whole bunch of trickery (parsing a tags body yourself or creating a `TagHelper` that targets everything) you can't do this 100% today (beta6).

You can partially fix your issue by ensuring `<inputField>` elements only appear inside of a `<blockSection>` tag (would not restrict you from putting things like `<p>` inside of a `<blockSection>`). Can be accomplished by using `context.Items` bag to notify an `InputFieldTagHelper` that it's (or is not) encapsulated by a `<blockSection>`. See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313529/how-to-render-scripts-generated-in-taghelper-process-method-to-the-bottom-of-t/31839554#31839554) for information on how to communicate between child => parent.

If you're willing to wait for [this Razor issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/255) to be completed; you'll be able to enforce what tags can appear inside your `TagHelper`.

Another similar SO [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790549/enclose-a-list-of-tags-taghelper-by-a-parent-tag/31839369#31839369) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This would be highly needed, any ideas when this  be resolved and be available?

Comment: It's next on my todo list. Hopefully beta7. Worst case beta8. :)

Comment: How do we future proof these tags? let's say W3C decides to make "blockSection" an official supported HTML5.x or 6.x tag?
I think the <asp:blockSection> was a good way to namespace it! 
Not sure why the MVC team went down the C# way, now back to XML tags...

Comment: You can always use the `@tagHelperPrefix "SomePrefix:"` to make it clear where TagHelpers are. By doing this it means you'd write your blockSection as so: `<SomePrefix:blockSection></SomePrefix:blockSection>`

Comment: Amazing!! this does exactly what I needed.